# SSH Remote Port Forwarding & “GatewayPorts yes” - Which Machine to Specify On

Tags: ssh

[This guide](https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html) to remote port forwarding says you need to add `GatewayPorts yes` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` when setting up remote SSH port forwarding.

But I cannot tell whether that needs to be added to the machine you are entering the `ssh` command into, or the machine you are remotely forwarding the port from.

Comment: I don't think `GatewayPorts yes` is a good idea. Much safer to use `GatewayPorts clientspecified`.

Comment: @kasperd - Is it possible to use clientspecified when the machine running `ssh -R` does not have a fixed IP?

Comment: No problem, `-R '[::]:2222:[::1]:22'` should work just fine if that's what you want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`GatewayPorts` is an option available for `sshd_config`, so it applies to the host you are connecting to.

Comment: Which computer is the host? The one running ssh -R or the other?

Comment: It is the other.

Comment: More info about the `GatewayPorts` option can be found on SSH Academy website: [https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example#remote-forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling-example#remote-forwarding)